# Search only working on front page (index) , not working on other pages

Tags: php, theme-development, permalinks, search, forms

I'm currently building a custom WordPress template and I've run into a problem with the search box.

When I use the searchbox from the homepage, it works as intended. It also works as long as Permalinks are set to default. (`url.com/?page_id=1`)

However, when I use the searchbox from another page when using pretty permalinks, the URL looks something like this:
`http://url.com/pretty-page-title/?s=query`
and a 404 page appears.

My search box code looks like this

`<form id="search-query">
    <div class="search-box">
        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="/index.php">
            <div>
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
                <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>`

Here's the site's URL if anyone's want to take a look: http://hermodsgymnasiet-develop.kaigan.modxcloud.com/

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Try `http://url.com/pretty-page-title/?s=query` with a bundled theme-- one of the "Twenty {Something}" ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your form looks like:

```
<form id="search-query">
    <p class="in-english"><a href="http://localhost/hermodswp/?page_id=76">Information in English</a></p>
    <div class="search-box">                
        <div>
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
            <input type="text" value="sdf" name="s" id="s" style="width: 293px;">
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Sök">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Try adjusting your submit action to point to your home_url().

```
action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"
```

You can edit the page in Chrome to see that this works fine.

```
<form role="search" id="search-query" method="get" action="http://hermodsgymnasiet-develop.kaigan.modxcloud.com/">
    <p class="in-english"><a href="http://localhost/hermodswp/?page_id=76">Information in English</a></p>
    <div class="search-box">        
        <div>
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" style="width: 293px;">
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Sök">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Only having one form, along with using home_url() solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `action="/"`to your form!